# Will javax.persistence.EntityManager.find return null if it fails to lock a row?

Tags: jpa, openjpa

From the javadoc, it said:
 T find(Class entityClass,
           Object primaryKey)
    Find by primary key.
    Parameters:
        entityClass -
        primaryKey -
    Returns:
        the found entity instance or null if the entity does not exist

When it fails to acquire lock for a record, does it return null also?

In my program, it seems like null is returned when it can't acquire a lock to the row involved.

Comment: I don't think find does any locking.

Comment: When I checked the logs, it translated to "Select ... for update", doesn't it mean lock?

Comment: If it's selecting for update, then indeed I was wrong, and find does lock in JPA.

Comment: Well, however, I found out the the if I call native SQL "Select ... for Update Wait 30". Maybe the lock releases too early before the transaction is completed.

Answer (score 0):

When `EntityManager.find()` fails to lock a row, it throws an exception. Here's one of my logs to prove it. In my case it tries to read an already locked record and fails after 20 seconds (OpenJPA 1.2.2 + Derby 10.6):

```
2011-10-14T16:33:22.882 [RemoteParameterStatusListenerInternalContainer-2] ERROR [c.v.r.r.i.g.RemoteParameterStatusInternalGatewayBean] - Exception in [...] org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Unable to obtain an object lock on "DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: 40001, SQLERRMC: Lock : ROW, PRODUCTSTATUS, (389,56)
  Waiting XID : {225252, S} [...], [query here]
  Granted XID : {225234, X} 
Lock : ROW, PRODUCTSTATUS, (389,57)
  Waiting XID : {225234, S} [...]
```

Comment: But how do you know if exception is thrown from executing the SQL or from EntityManager.find()?

Comment: It's always SQL underneath. Em.find() uses SQL to find the record.